# Check if a cookie is set and if true launch function

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a problem, i have a Zopim chat and a cookie consent.. I only want the chat to show if the cookie consent is given.

Now, the button is clicked after page load and it is done. now i want to add an event listener to check if the cookie is set and then launch the zopim chat without reloading the page.

My javascript:

```
function OpenChat(){


  $zopim(function() {
    $zopim.livechat.window.show();
  });



}

document.cookie('cookieconsent_dismissed').addEventListener('change', OpenChat(), true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mate, sorry, you can not add a listener for cookie change event, it's not possilble yet,

you need do a timer query the cookie value and check, it's how the jquery $fileDown load works, keepking check the cookie value with a timer,

```
 function listenCookieChange(cookieName, callback) {
setInterval(function() {
    if (cookieRegistry[cookieName]) {
        if (readCookie(cookieName) != cookieRegistry[cookieName]) {
            // update registry so we dont get triggered again
            cookieRegistry[cookieName] = readCookie(cookieName);
            return callback();
        }
    } else {
        cookieRegistry[cookieName] = readCookie(cookieName);
    }
}, 100);
}
```

there is a complete sample for you mate, check : 
http://jsfiddle.net/8pzkggv0/